# converting column data to uppercase in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a data set as df in thich i have

```
country| indicator|date|year&week| value
```

as columns name, I want to convert data of only  country column to upper case using pyspark (only data not heading)
i tried

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.select("*", f.upper("country"))
display(df)
```

but it has error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'select'

Comment: `df.select()` doesn't modify the dataframe in place, it returns a new df. `print(df.select(...))`

Comment: it still has same error

Comment: Have you looked at my answer? @RahulKumar

Answer (score 2):

I would have not used `select` because select does not change the dataframe it gives a new dataframe with an added column of your resulting function data.

I used `withColumn` and it works just fine, please refer to the following code snippet:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
import pandas as pd

# Sample Data
data = {
  "country": ["United States", "Canada", "spain", "germany"],
  "indicator": ["1", "2", "3", "4"],
  "date": ["2022/01/01", "2021/01/01", "2020/01/01", "2019/01/01"],
  "year&week": ["2022-52", "2021-34", "2020-32", "2019-45"],
  "value": ["56", "28", "258", "425"]
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
# Convert to spark dataframe
df = spark.createDataFrame(df)
# Apply your function to the column you choose
df = df.withColumn("country", f.upper(f.col("country")))
```

Now you can check with `df.show()` or `display(df)` and you'll get the following output:

```py
df.show()
+-------------+---------+----------+---------+-----+
|      country|indicator|      date|year&week|value|
+-------------+---------+----------+---------+-----+
|UNITED STATES|        1|2022/01/01|  2022-52|   56|
|       CANADA|        2|2021/01/01|  2021-34|   28|
|        SPAIN|        3|2020/01/01|  2020-32|  258|
|      GERMANY|        4|2019/01/01|  2019-45|  425|
+-------------+---------+----------+---------+-----+
```

Answer (score -2):

When you want to change a column's value, withColumn is better than changing it in select statement.

withColumn syntax--> withColumn(new col name, value)

so when you give the new col name as "country" and the value as f.upper("country"), the column name will remain same and the original column value will be replaced with upper case of country names.

```
simpleData = [["Canada","Y"],["Spain","N"],["Brazil","Y"],
   ["Japan","Y"],["India","N"] ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(simpleData,["country","indicator"])

#input 

display(df)


import pyspark.sql.functions as f

upperDf=df.withColumn("country", f.upper("country"))

#output

display(upperDf)
```

Comment: Please add a little explanation! This would help future visitors finding this question & answer pair.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Joooeey! I have added some explanation, hope it helps.